# Layout color should change in respective to alphabets

Tags: android, text, view, colors, background

Hi in my project am having a layout and an text view which contains only one alphabet like A,B to Z, now I want to fix back ground color of each alphabet. How can I do this ?

Comment: share some code that u tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a switch statement and assign color. If you textview name is `text` then

```
 String myalphabet=text.getText().toString();
 switch(myalphabet)
 { 
 case A: 
 text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 break;
 case B:
 text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
 break;
 so on .......
 }
```

You can also set color by

```
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

or

```
text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
text.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0));
```

If you want to define your color in an XML then

```
<color name="errorColor">#f00</color>
```

and then use this code to show it:

```
text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor));
```

Comment: That idea I good, but my list consists of names from A to Z if user register with name A--- I should make textview red if with B--- green,,, Z---- blue